# Unable to run node server in angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am getting an error while running node server. The error is

[image: error]

I also tried many solutions given in [example](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/663), but nothing is working. ng serve is working. I've created a server file and also installed node express module. I've followed these [instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JaUPlmsCwI&index=54&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwg5gEu2KF4sbGvpUqMRSBSW) to create the server.

Server.js file code is

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const api = require('./server/routes/api');
const port = 3000;

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'dist')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api',api);
app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendfile(path.json(__dirname,'dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log("server is running on localhost: " + port);
});
```

and server/routers/api

```
const express= require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/',function(req,res){
res.send('api works');

});

module.exports= router
```

Comment: Only if you show ur code, someone would be able to find the issue.

Comment: I've updated both files code

Comment: express and body parser both I've installed

Comment: what is the full error ? which module it could't find ?

Comment: the cmd is error which I'm getting while running node server. I don't know much about node and angularjs

Comment: The image that you have included has the error. But you have scraped it.

Comment: well i got it.. the server file was on wrong order.

Comment: Didn’t you mean `require(“./server/routers/api”)`? In the current require, it references `./server/routes/api`.

Comment: server.js file was on wrong order